# How do I find Word Error Rate of all the sentences present in the file?

Tags: python, data-processing

I was given this dummy code for Microsoft Speech Recognition Lab.
I am trying to find word error rate(individually as well as sum) of all the sentences stored in the file.

I have loaded the files in memory using Numpy arrays now I am struggling to find the sentence error rate for each sentence present in the file. There are a total of three sentences and I want my program to go through each sentence and compute the word error rate. My loop runs thrice yet the result is only being accumulated for the first sentence. Have a look at my code and guide me where am I going wrong. Thanks.

**Provided Code:**

```
def string_edit_distance(ref="ref_data", hyp="hyp_data"):

    if ref is None or hyp is None:
        RuntimeError("ref and hyp are required, cannot be None")

    x = ref
    y = hyp
    tokens = len(x)
        if (len(hyp)==0):
            return (tokens, tokens, tokens, 0, 0)

    # p[ix,iy] consumed ix tokens from x, iy tokens from y
    p = np.PINF * np.ones((len(x) + 1, len(y) + 1)) # track total errors
    e = np.zeros((len(x)+1, len(y) + 1, 3), dtype=np.int) # track deletions, insertions, substitutions
    p[0] = 0
    for ix in range(len(x) + 1):
        for iy in range(len(y) + 1):
            cst = np.PINF*np.ones([3])
            s = 0
            if ix > 0:
                cst[0] = p[ix - 1, iy] + 1 # deletion cost
            if iy > 0:
                cst[1] = p[ix, iy - 1] + 1 # insertion cost
            if ix > 0 and iy > 0:
                s = (1 if x[ix - 1] != y[iy -1] else 0)
                cst[2] = p[ix - 1, iy - 1] + s # substitution cost
            if ix > 0 or iy > 0:
                idx = np.argmin(cst) # if tied, one that occurs first wins
                p[ix, iy] = cst[idx]

                if (idx==0): # deletion
                    e[ix, iy, :] = e[ix - 1, iy, :]
                    e[ix, iy, 0] += 1
                elif (idx==1): # insertion
                    e[ix, iy, :] = e[ix, iy - 1, :]
                    e[ix, iy, 1] += 1
                elif (idx==2): # substitution
                    e[ix, iy, :] = e[ix - 1, iy - 1, :]
                    e[ix, iy, 2] += s

edits = int(p[-1,-1])
deletions, insertions, substitutions = e[-1, -1, :]
```

**What I have Tried Till Now:**

```
with open("misc/hyp.trn") as f:
    hyp_data = f.readlines()
with open("misc/ref.trn") as f:
    ref_data = f.readlines()

hypData = []
refData = []

for lines in hyp_data:             
    hypData.append(lines[:][:-20])

for line in ref_data:
    refData.append(line[:][:-20])

for i in range(len(hypData)):

    print("Line Number: ",i, refData[i], hypData[i])

    print("Total number of reference sentences in the test set: ", len(refData))

    print("Number of sentences with an error", len(hypData))

    print("Total number of reference words", tokens)

    print("Total number of word substitutions, insertions, and deletions: ")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")

    print("Scores: N="+str(tokens)+", S="+str(substitutions)+", D= "+str(deletions)+", 
    I="+str(insertions))

    print("The percentage of total errors (WER) and percentage of substitutions, insertions, and 
    deletions")

    wer = (deletions+insertions+substitutions)/tokens
    print("The percentage of total errors (WER): ", int((wer*100)*10 + 0.5)/10)
    print("Percentage of substitutions: ", int((substitutions*100 + 0.5)/10))
    print("Percentage of insertions: ", int((insertions*100 + 0.5)/10))
    print("Percentage of deletions: ",int((deletions*100 + 0.5)/10))

string_edit_distance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the punctuation then calculate WER on the text only.

Refer to this [repository](https://github.com/duckyngo/Word-Error-Rate-Visualization-with-Colab) to calculate the Word Error Rate (WER) of two strings with Colab.

You can also remove the punctuation when calculate WER by tick on the remote_punctuation checkbox.

[image]